# How to efficiently use a index array as a mask to turn a numpy array into a boolean array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
>>> I
array([[ 1.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.]])
```

And an array A like this:

```
>>> A = np.ones((2,5,3))
```

I'd like to obtain the following matrix:

```
>>> result
array([[[ False,  False,  True],
        [ False,  True,  True],
        [ False,  False,  False],
        [ False,  False,  True],
        [ False,  True,  True]],

       [[ False,  True,  True],
        [ False,  False,  False],
        [ False,  False,  True],
        [ False,  True,  True],
        [ False,  False,  False]]], dtype=bool)
```

It is better to explain with an example: 
 `I[0,0] = 1 -> result[0,0,:2] = False` and `result[1,1,2:] = True` 
 `I[1,0] = 0 -> result[1,1,0] = False` and `result[1,1,1:] = True`

Here is my current implementation (correct):

```
result = np.empty((A.shape[0], A.shape[1], A.shape[2]))
r = np.arange(A.shape[2])
for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
    result[i] = r > np.vstack(I[i])

print result.astype(np.bool)
```

Is there a way to implement in a faster way (avoiding the for loop)?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run your code, but it does not work for me. Could you revise your question and make it clearer?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. A is a (2,5,3) matrix. I added also a print with the bool conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another dimension on to `I`, such that you can broadcast `r` properly:

```
result = r > I.reshape(I.shape[0],I.shape[1],1)
```

e.g.

```
In [41]: r>I.reshape(2,5,1)
Out[41]: 
array([[[False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True]],

       [[False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```